# Sorting lists of strings

Tags: c#

When I try to sort a list of strings in C#, the result is kinda strange,

```
List<string> a = new List<string>();
a.Add("test1");
a.Add("test12");
a.Add("bbb");
a.Add("a");
a.Add("aaa");
a.Add("AAAaaAA");
a.Sort();
```

What I am left with is

```
a
bbb
test1
test12
aaa
AAAaaAA
```

I do not get why

```
aaa 
AAAaaAA
```

is at the end?
Can anyone explain why this is so?

Comment: Please clarify how you are verifying the result after `Sort` is called. I see a different result https://dotnetfiddle.net/0xXTNE

Comment: Here is an example which vesually looks the same way https://dotnetfiddle.net/92H2eY but the difference is that "a" in the bottom are different chars. It is not the result of copy-paste from the question.

Comment: @sarh What an awesome catch!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because of your culture. I'm a Dane, and I get the same results. (Probadly because "aa" is an "å").

```
 System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en");
```

Add this before your list, then you'll get the expected.

For others to replicate the problem:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("da");
```

Solution:

```
a.Sort(StringComparer.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Dane here as well,so this might be the problem yes.
Is it possible to use the "en" culture for only the specific sort?

Comment: To fix the problem: a.Sort(StringComparer.InvariantCulture);

Comment: The wording of the answer may be off, but it's correct about the basic reason why the results are what they are. I'm not a Dane, but if I flew to where you are and executed the same code on your computer it would give me the same result. But I understand what you mean.